# Stop text from moving on a:hover with border top

Tags: css

I have a floated an `h2 a` tag with a 6px `border-top` applied on hover. When I hover over the text it pushes the text and elements below it down. How can I stop the border from moving the text and other elements? Thanks!

My CSS:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block
}

body {
  line-height: 1
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: none
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
  border-top: 8px solid black;
}

h2 a {
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 94px;
  color: black;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

h2 a:hover {
  border-top: 6px solid orange;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.clocknotes {
  width: 437px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  clear: both;
}

.brand-three {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 85px;
}

.brand-three {
  font-size: 200px;
  line-height: 140px;
  float: left;
  letter-spacing: -20px;
}

.quote {
  clear: both;
  width: 417px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: -250px;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.social {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -80px;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
h2 a:hover {
    border-top: 6px solid orange;
    padding-top:14px;

}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/VyRZW/

Answer (score 3):

Reduce top padding for an equal amount, not to zero:

```
h2 a:hover {
border-top: 6px solid orange;
padding-top: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this code:

```
h2 a {border-top: 6px solid #fff;} /* Should match your background color */
```

Comment: I still want the border to show up and be orange. I just want it to stop moving everything else. An effect similar to the links here, notice the border when hovering over the links at the top. http://jasonsantamaria.com/

Comment: To "match the background color" without effort, you can always set the border color to `transparent`.